# Are the foundations of mathematics "doomed" to be set-theoretic in nature?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics, set-theory, foundations-of-mathematics

Let's say we want to come up with a foundational theory for all of mathematics and let's say that it is embedded in first-order logic. Note that the machinery of first-order logic is described with set-theoretical notions, in a meta-theoretical sense.

Why doesn't meta-theoretical use of sets while laying down a foundational theory (intended to avoid sets in an object-theoretical sense) undermine the whole enterprise?

Comment: Interesting discussion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2509877/are-category-theory-and-set-theory-on-the-equal-foundational-footing) about set theory vs. category theory as a foundation for mathematics

Comment: Well, mathematical foundations don't need to be embedded in FOL. In "From Set Theory to Type Theory", Mike Shulman describes how type theory isn't built on FOL, even though it has FOL: https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2013/01/from_set_theory_to_type_theory.html

Comment: Keep in mind that in modern times, one of the main applications of formal logic is to be a tool for *doing* mathematics and computer science, most of the development of formal logic you see is in a form suitable for that application.

With the foundational crisis long behind us, there isn't widespread interest in that particular application of formal logic. And given that there are systematic ways to translate between different approaches to the topic, there is even less interest in the *specific form* in which foundations takes.

Comment: @Hurkyl this sounds like something worth elaborating into a full answer.